# Stripping Line Breaks in Tweets via Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm looking pull data from the Twitter API and create a pipe separated file that I can do further processing on.  My code currently looks like this:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

out_file = "tweets.txt"

tweets = api.search(q='foo')
o = open(out_file, 'a')

for tweet in tweets:
        id = str(tweet.id)
        user = tweet.user.screen_name
        post = tweet.text
        post = post.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        post = post.strip('|') # so pipes in tweets don't create unwanted separators
        post = post.strip('\r\n')
        record = id + "|" + user + "|" + post
        print>>o, record
```

I have a problem when a user's tweet includes line breaks which makes the output data look like this:

```
473565810326601730|usera|this is a tweet 
473565810325865901|userb|some other example 
406478015419876422|userc|line 
separated 
tweet
431658790543289758|userd|one more tweet
```

I want to strip out the line breaks on the third tweet.  I've tried post.strip('\n') and post.strip('0x0D 0x0A') in addition to the above but none seem to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) returns "a copy of the string with **leading** and **trailing** characters removed".

You should use [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) for the new line and for the pipe:

```
post = post.replace('|', ' ')
post = post.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Comment: This appears to have worked.  Thanks.  I don't exactly understand why replace works for the newline but not strip, but I think you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: The newlines you want to remove are in the middle of the string, not at the end or beginning of the string. `strip` only works if you want to remove something from the "edges".